# Can I set docker container labels based on output of previous run command during build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I wonder if is possible to set a LABEL during building of a container with a based that is based on a command run on the container.

Example, wanting to expose `python=2.7.14` when the number would be obtained from running `python --version` during build.

The idea is to expose some information about what was build as labels, before starting the build these versions are not known (like packages installed using yum).

Comment: This would be really useful and seems like a natural requirement in multi-stage builds. Are you aware of any changes in the meantime, or feature requests?

Comment: Looking to do pretty much exactly this right now, take it neither of you got anywhere @Raphael @Sorin?

Comment: You could give a try to this approach. Note, I am not sure if this would suffice your requirement. There might be a way to get the value of version and write it to some file (and keep the file in host volume). Use this file to set the label to container in next run by using the following command `$ docker run --label-file ./labels ubuntu bash` [docker run with labels](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-metadata-on-container--l---label---label-file)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is just not possible.
You need to use [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) before launching the build.